# SSH in Shell to populate array with system information from remote host

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ssh

```
ssh $remote '( df -k )' > $REMOTE_SPACE
for (( i=0; i<no_dest; i++ ))
    do
        ssh $remote "( aux_free_space[i]=$( du -sk ${aux_dest[${i}]}  | cut -f 1 ) )"
    done
```

All work ok apart from populating the array aux_free_space[]; i think the du runs on the local host.

- ssh $remote works fine
- aux_free_space is initialised at the beginning
- aux_dest is already populated

Comment: also tried:
`ssh $remote '( aux_free_space[i]=$( du -sk ${aux_mount[${i}]}  | cut -f 1 ) )' `

Comment: and
`ssh $remote ' aux_free_space[i]=$( du -sk ${aux_mount[${i}]}  | cut -f 1 ) ' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh $remote df -k > $REMOTE_SPACE

for ((i = 0; i < no_dest; i++)); do
    aux_free_space[i]=$(ssh $remote du -sk ${aux_dest[i]} | cut -f 1)
done
```

The array assignment has to be pulled out into the local shell, but the `du` must be done remotely. The `cut` can be done on either side, so to cut down on the levels of quoting you can do it locally. (If `du` returned a lot of output you might choose to do the `cut` remotely to cut down on network traffic.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Will keep it in mind.
From what I understand in this case the cut is done remotely.  If it were to be done locally  would it be?:
`aux_free_space[i]=$(ssh $remote du -sk ${aux_dest[i]}) | cut -f 1`

Comment: As I wrote it the cut is local. To do it remotely, write `aux_free_space[i]=$(ssh $remote "du -sk ${aux_dest[i]} | cut -f 1")`.